# IE keeps blocking add-on

Tags: java, internet-explorer, browser-addons

I have tried both IE 8 and 9. Now I have a website that needs to run a java plugin/add-on, but IE keeps blocking it. I have done everything I can think of and reading on google on how to allow it, but it does not work. I have tried the following settings in IE (Internet Options) without success:

- Disabled Pop-Up blocker
- Added site to Safe Senders list
- Enabled ALL Active X and Java Scripting settings under Internet Options>Security>Custom level
- Allow active content to run files on my PC (Advanced tab)
- Tried Java 7u25, Java7u51
- Change the security param in Java Control Panel Applet

Nothing works. How can I make sure that the Java Add-on is allowed on IE

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you adjust the security settings in the Java control Panel applet to allow integration with IE?

Comment: Yip, did that as well

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with settings in compatibility mode?

Also, IE 9 is still two major revisions behind.  I wouldn't recommend going to IE 11 quite yet, but an install of IE 10 might help.  I don't recall the exact details, but I had this problem with a plugin with a couple months ago and was resolved by updating IE (which I hardly used).